# Set the toolbar color, which is set in the card

Tags: android

I have RecyclerView + cards. In the cards I set the random color in class ViewHolder -

```
`       int[] androidColors = view.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidColors);
        int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
        if (frameLayout != null) {
            frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
        }`
```

By clicking on the card, open activity. And the color of her toolbar should be like that of a card.

Intent putExtra I can not use here, because in the intent, I already pass the tag.

```
 public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        ....

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long poemId = (Long) v.getTag();
                onPoemClickListener.onPoemClick(poemId);

            }
        });
    }
}

public interface OnPoemClickListener {
    void onPoemClick(long poemId);

}
```

fragment class where recycler is located

```
   private final PoemsAdapter.OnPoemClickListener onPoemClickListener = new PoemsAdapter.OnPoemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPoemClick(long poemId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReadActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ReadActivity.EXTRA_POEM_ID, poemId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

How can I get the random color that I generate in the adapter in activity? Thank!

Comment: just use a bundle, intent.putExtras(Bundle bundle)

Answer (score 0):

You can put as many extras as you want:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReadActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ReadActivity.EXTRA_POEM_ID, poemId);
intent.putExtra("mycolor", color);
startActivity(intent);
```

then get it in the activity that opens, just like you get any other extra value,

Comment: intent is called in onPoemClickListener, and interface OnPoemClickListener has one argument - poemId. 
In order for me to put a color, it must be registered in the arguments of the interface, otherwise it will turn red

Comment: So if you have created an interface that does not suit your needs, change it for  OnPoemClickListener to accept 2 arguments.